# Find difference between two dataframes of large data

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to get the difference in data between two dataframes. I'm using `subtract()` for this.

```
# Dataframes that need to be compared
df1 
df2

#df1-df2
new_df1 = df1.subtract(df2)

#df2-df1
new_df2 = df2.subtract(df1)
```

It works fine and the output is what I needed, but my only issue is with the performance.

Even for comparing 1gb of data, it takes around 50 minutes, which is far from ideal.

Is there any other optimised method to perform the same operation?

Following are some of the details regarding the dataframes:

- df1 size = 9397995 * 30
- df2 size = 1500000 * 30
- All 30 columns are of dtype `string`.
- Both dataframes are being loaded from a database through jdbc
  connection.
- Both dataframes have same column names and in same order.

Comment: What exactly are you after? Want you to know if the dataframes differ or also to know where they differ?

Comment: I want to know where they differ. For example, if some data is present in `df1` and not present in `df2`, `df1-df2` should provide me with a new dataframe that has the difference in data.

Comment: Which kind of dataframes do you use? How are they created? Where does the data come from? Why a dataframe?

Comment: "Even for comparing 1gb of data, it takes around 50 minutes" what does "1 GB of data" mean exactly? Why don't you tell us some specifics about the actual dataframes you are working with, e.g `df.size`, `df.dtypes` etc etc

Comment: For example, if I create a dataframe with 1 gigabytes all `np.float64`, and do the `df.subtract` operation, it takes 540 milliseconds.

Comment: Provided some of the details @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: hmm I'm wondering why you are using substract which is meant to substract a value. Is there a specific column you are trying to substract? You can try dropping the duplicates if what you want is to remove those that are similar -> pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, you cannot `.subtract` strings. This should raise an error. What do you expect `df.subtract(df)` to do when the columns only have dtype `pd.StringDtype()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "WHERE" statement on a dataset to filter out rows you don't need. For example through PK, if you know that df1 has pk ranging from 1 to 100, you just filter in df2 for all those pk's. Obviously after a union

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).